# Including dynamic pages in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I've a Java WebApp. I have put some attributes inside the context and init params to get them when I needed.

Content of **head.jspf**:

```
<link href="${initParam['bootstrap_css_cdn']}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="${applicationScope['css_dir']}basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

From **index.jsp**, if I do this:

```
<jsp:include page="WEB-INF/jspf/head.jspf" />
```

it works perfectly!

But if I do this:

```
<jsp:include page="${applicationScope['headURL']}"
```

it doesn't work at all (the "headURL" variable is a string with the right URL). I mean, the jspf is included but, for example, the following code is written in the final html code literally:

```
${applicationScope['css_dir']}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSPF files are not compiled. They're supposed to be included statically, not dynamically (i.e. with `<%@include %>`). Change the extension to .jsp if you want a dynamic include.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JBMizet wrote in a comment:

> JSPF files are not compiled. They're supposed to be included statically, not dynamically (i.e. with <%@include %>). Change the extension to .jsp if you want a dynamic include.

Comment: ([Comment converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat))